# bind click event with close the kendo window

Tags: window, kendo-ui

i am using kendo window.
and i have contain on them other html view.
in this html i have one button. when i click on this button i want to close the current window.

```
<div id="window" class="k-window-content k-content" style="overflow: auto;" data-role="window" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="window_wnd_title">
    <iframe class="k-content-frame" frameborder="0" src="http://localhost/eventBot/index.php/parsePortal/scrapePortalSite/5623" title="">
    <html class="k-ff k-ff23">
    <head>
    <body>
    <div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="window">
        <div class="block_content" data-role="tooltip">
           <form id="siteConfigForm" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="http://localhost/eventBot/index.php/parsePortal/saveConfig" data-role="validator" novalidate="novalidate">
           <table>
              <tr>
              <td>
                   <button class="k-button save" onclick="siteConfig()" type="button">Save</button>
                   <button class="k-button" onclick="windowss()" type="button">close</button>
              </td>
              </tr>
           </table>
           </form>
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

in this html i have save button when i click on this i want to bind `window.close();`

how can i do this.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't duplicate IDs within the same document. example of your siteConfig function:

```
function siteConfig() {
    // ...
    // some useful code

    $("#window").data("kendoWindow").close();
});
```

or write click event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.save', function (e) {
        $("#window").data("kendoWindow").close();
    });
```

read kendo documentation about window here: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/index.html

Comment: yes i remove this same id and got this error  $(...).data(...) is null

Comment: problem is solve i am just use `$("#popup").kendoWindow({content: {
         url: "<?php echo site_url('home/test')?>/"+userID,
         },});` its totaly wrong its create a new html view inside iframe and this is work `content: "home/test/"+userID,`